# Know if AngularJS directive method binding defaults to angular.noop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a simple directive that passes a function on to a plugin; the plugin will then use the function with a given value. For simplicity, let's ignore changes on the data:

```
angular.module('some.directives', [])
  .directive('myDirective', [,
    function () {
      return {
        restrict: 'EAC',
        scope: {
          value: '@', // some value
          fun: '&' // the function
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          ThePlugin.thisIsTheVal(scope.value);
          ThePlugin.thisIsTheFun(scope.fun);
        }
      };
    }
  ]);
```

The problem is: when the `fun` attribute is not defined or the parent scope doesn't have the specified function, `ThePlugin` will always execute `angular.noop`, as that seems to be the default AngularJS provides.

Since I need to pass a real `undefined` when the function is not defined, how can I know if the calling scope actually has the function?

A workaround may consist in testing the function against the target value, and then return `undefined` if the resulting value is `undefined` itself:

```
ThePlugin.thisIsTheFun(function() {
  if (scope.fun(scope.value) === undefined) {
    return scope.fun;
  }
  return undefined;
});
```

This may lead to some inconsistencies, since it may be that the `fun` function will be allowed to return `undefined` as a proper result in the future.

Comment: Try this: `ThePlugin.thisIsTheFun(scope.fun !== angular.noop ? scope.fun : undefined)`. Maybe it's the same noop function (haven't tested)

Comment: The thing is, `scope.fun` is never (directly) equal to `angular.noop` but it returns a `parentGet(scope, locals)` that would later be evaluated to the target function in the caller scope. I have also tried to check `$parse(attrs['fun']) === angular.noop` but this only works when the attribute is not set and not, for example, when the attribute is set but the function is not found.

Comment: Oh, yeah. You are absolutely right! It is actually a function that "wraps" the expression that is given in the template. BTW, a colleague was complaining about this thing where he wanted to behave like "if the function is given, do this, otherwise do something else" in order to be more "flexible" in the way the directive was used. We realized that the overall design was more complex than it should have been and re-thought the whole thing.

Comment: I agree, but in my case the design does not depend on my decisions, since I am integrating with an external plugin.

Comment: For me it worked using `scope.fun = (attrs.hasOwnProperty('fun') ? scope.fun : undefined);`
Maybe a later version of angular has "fixed" this? :) Cause I had this exact issue..

Answer (score 1):

Check if the `fun` attribute is defined:

```
if (!attrs.hasOwnProperty('fun')) {
   scope.fun = undefined;
}
```

Comment: I have specified in the second comment to the question that "I have also tried to check `$parse(attrs['fun']) === angular.noop` but this only works when the attribute is not set and not, for example, when the attribute is set but the function is not found.".

Comment: @frapontillo Why would the expression contain an undefined function? And even if: Why should the directive care? It's an error condition after all.

Comment: There are three possibilities: 1) the attribute is not set, therefore the function will be resolved to angular.noop, 2) the attribute is set and the function exists, 3) the attribute is set but the function does not exist.

Comment: @frapontillo got that, but 3 doesn't make sense to me and I still don't know why the directive should care. I would only write `<my-directive fun="x()">` if `x` actually existed, wouldn't I? I wouldn't call `x` if I knew it doesn't exist.

Comment: Of course, but that happens in an ideal world; there might be a syntax error, or the function may have not been defined _yet_, so the directive would want to handle the particular case.

Comment: @frapontillo No, it wouldn't want to, but I respect your opinion on that issue. If the expression only contains a single function call, then you can check the parent scope for the existence of that function.